# waypoint.js not working in second section

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, jquery-waypoints

In my code i want on each section i scroll the elements will visible but which  is not happening. In first section it is working perfectly but not in second section,I am actually using the fullpage.js as well.But all is working properly except the waypoint.js at second section

```
$('.ianimator').waypoint(function() {
  $('.ianimator').addClass('animated fadeIn');   
},{offset:'90%'});

$('.secmator').waypoint(function() {
  $('.secmato').addClass('animated fadeIn');   
},{offset:'90%'});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c5eszqkw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) you'll realise that libraries relying on the scroll event won't work in fullPage.js unless you use the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false`.

Personally I would recommend you to make use of [fullPage.js state classes](http://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) or [callbacks](http://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) to achieve those animations. This way you can use any fullPage.js configuration.

[Here's a video tutorial I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=1s) regarding css3 animations and the use of fullpage.js state classes.

Comment: I want the waypoint.js animation and i have already added the scrollBar:true to my code still it's not working,Nad i noticed that after open the page i go to last div it's animating,so i think all the elements are animating at the same time,so i can see the animation on 1st section only.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not initializing fullPage.js, I can not test what you say. Please update the jsfiddle with the fullpage.js initialization and files to reproduce your issue.